# Return variable in an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, url

I have a javascript code that returns a variable called `foo`

I need to pass this variable as text to an onclick function

```js
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

var foo = getQueryVariable("dv1");
```

```html
<ul class="answer-list">
 <li><a class="btn rollover" onclick="nextQuestion(6, 'http://www.example.net/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjMIWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1=FOOHERE');"><span>Yes</span></a></li>
 <li><a class="btn rollover" onclick="nextQuestion(6, 'http://www.example.net/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjMIWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1=FOOHERE');"><span>No</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to know how to pass the variable `foo` into the onclick function link in the place of **FOOHERE**.

how to do that in order to get the correct link ?

Comment: declare function `nextQuestion(num, link){}`

Comment: it's a long code and not related to the question I just need to know how to pass the var in place of FOOHERE... I need the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call another function with two parameters, and the another function will call nextQuestion

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="answer-list">
    <li><a class="btn rollover" onclick="someFunc(6, 'http://www.example.net/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjMIWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1=');"><span>Yes</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn rollover" onclick="someFunc(6, 'http://www.example.net/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjMIWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1=');"><span>No</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

function someFunc(number, link) {
    link = link + getQueryVariable("dv1");
    nextQuestion(number, link )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code

```js
function nextQuestion(num, link){
    var val = link.replace(/.*&dv1=/, "");
    console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="nextQuestion(6, 'http://www.example.net/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjMIWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1=FOOHERE1');">Yes</a>
<a onclick="nextQuestion(6, 'http://www.example.net/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjMIWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1=FOOHERE2');">No</a>
```